# Move a graph within a certain range - MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

The graph should be moved right, down, left, up, consecutively, and then loop this process again ->infinitely until the program is ended. When I tried my mips code as follows, the image can move right, then down, but stuck in the move_left part.

```
 move:
push ra
lw      t7, frame_counter           
li      t4, 10                  
rem     t3, t7, t4                   
bne     t3, 0, _move_image_exit 

_move_image_right:
    lw  t1, image_x                 
    inc t1                  
    bgt t1, 17, _move_image_down            
    sw  t1, image_x
    j   _move_image_exit

_move_image_down:
    lw  t0, image_y
    inc t0
    bgt     t0, 5, _move_image_left
    sw  t0, image_y
    j   _move_image_exit

_move_image_left:
    lw  t1, image_x
    dec t1
    blt     t1, 5, _move_image_up
    sw  t1, image_x
    b   _move_image_exit

_move_image_up:
    lw  t0, image_y
    dec t0
    blt t0, 2, _move_image_right
    sw  t0, image_y
    b   _move_image_exit

#_store_image_coordinates:
    #sw     t1, image_x
    #sw     t0, image_y
_move_image_exit:   
 pop ra
 jr ra
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I have not enough reputation to comment...

If I understand it correctly, when you arrive in `_move_image_left` your value in `image_x` is greater than 17 otherwise you wouldn't have reached the block, so the blt doesn't branch and you go directly to the `_move_image_exit`